Graduate Textbook Recommendations for Second-Order Logic
I'm currently reading Bruno Poizat's A Course on Model Theory and am interested in possibly extending model theory to second-order logic. I'm looking for recommendations on graduate-level textbooks that offer a rigorous treatment of second-order logic, particularly in terms of semantics, proof theory, and its applications in model theory. Any suggestions for texts that would complement my current studies and support this extension would be greatly appreciated. I should clarify that I am familiar with Henkin's semantics and advanced set theory so I would be appreciative for additional books beyond what was recommended by the first question.

@TankutBeygu Having read through it I saw a few good recommendations I will check out. But the last question wanted standard semantics where I am looking for Henkin's. Thank you!

I have voted to reopen this question as the OP has clarified they are interested in Henkin semantics, not in standard semantics, which is the subject addressed in the flagged dupe
